# Improving on the efficiency of my filtering of arrays with potentially hundreds of thousands of elements

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I have an array of numbers. I want to find those in `array1` that aren't also in `array2`, like this:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var array2 = [2, 4, 5, 6]

var result = [1, 3]
```

I've solved the problem by looping through all the numbers in the `array2` and adding them to a dictionary. Then I loop through `array1` and add those that aren't in the dictionary to the result array:

```
var result: [Int] = []
var numbersDict: [Int : Bool] = [:]

for element in array2 {
  numbersDict[element] = true
}

for element in array1 {
  if numbersDict[element] == nil {
    result.append(element)
  }
}
```

I also want to find those in `array2` that aren't in `array1`

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var array2 = [2, 4, 5, 6]

var result = [5, 6]
```

I've solved this like this:

```
var result: [Int] = []
var numbersDict: [Int : Bool] = [:]

for element in array1 {
  numbersDict[element] = true
}

for element in array2 {
  if numbersDict[element] == nil {
    result.append(element)
  }
}
```

How can I do this in the most efficient way? Assuming that these arrays could potentially be tens if not hundreds of thousands of numbers long. Should I be using sorting?

Comment: if the elements in the arrays are unique, I would remove elements from the dictionary as I find them in array2. At the end, the dictionary holds the elements in array1 that are not in array2. If such an optimization is not possible, Just create a dictionary of the elements in array2 as you built its results. Then run a loop for array1 and check on it like you are doing for array2 already.

Comment: @user1984 they are unique yeah. In ‘real life’ the numbers actually are unique users with ids. I just simplified it to numbers here. Can you give an example of that, I’m not sure I understand exactly?

Comment: sure, you don't mind me giving it in pseudo code or python? I'm not a swift person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`Set`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set).

Example which gets elements in `array1` but not in `array2`:

```
let array1: Set = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let array2: Set = [2, 4, 5, 6]

let result = array1.subtracting(array2)
print(result)
// Prints: [1, 3]  <- Order may vary since it is a set
```

Just switch the two sets around to get the opposite result, of in `array2` but not in `array1`.

There are lots of `Set` operations, another one is [`intersection(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853807-intersection):

```
let result = array1.intersection(array2)
print(result)
// Prints: [2, 4]  <- Again, no order
```